# net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE on loading url android webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am using android webview to load a website and got the following error

```
net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

I just want to know why i am getting this error. I don't find any helpful reference related to this
error.

Thanks,

Comment: Any reference might be helpful.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, the site which is working fine in any mobile browser but when I try to load it in webview I get the same error. What is the reason and is there any solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request){
            Log.d("WebViewActivity", request.getUrl().toString());
            if( request.getUrl().toString().startsWith("http:") || request.getUrl().toString().startsWith("https:") ) {



            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()));
            startActivity( intent );
            return true;
        }
```

if in the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method do not do

```
view.loadUrl (String.valueOf (request.getUrl ()));
return false;
```

the error disappears